# Access form "jumping" to another record on save. Access Front End, SQL Server Back End. Jumping to ID based on DB trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, triggers

Here's something just whacky that I've been pulling my hair out over.

The project is an Access front end, where the tables have recently been moved to a SQL Server back end. Access will be providing form/report/etc tools for the end user.

An odd behaviour has cropped up. When creating a new record, and adding any given data to any given subform, upon saving that data, the subform "jumps" to another record. The data as entered is accurately saved. If the main form is refreshed, the data displayed in the subform is accurate. It's only after saving the data in a subform that the displayed record jumps.

> **Example**: This is an employee database. We add a new employee (Bob). There is a subform for education and credentials. We enter Bob's credentials. We navigate outside the subform (or manually save it, either way). Bob's credentials then "jump" to another set of credentials. (Let's say Jack's). Bob's credentials are saved, and if we refresh our view of Bob, we see them, but we only see Jack's credentials until that point. The record for Jack's credentials are not altered in any way.

At first, I thought the location it was jumping to was completely random. It turns out that it is not.

Very recently, an audit log needed to be built for this database. A series of triggers was setup for this purpose. Basic stuff. For every table that gets an update, delete, or insert, capture that change and log it. The trigger used is a slight variant on this popular [Pop Rivetts solution](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/).

I mention this audit log because I noticed that the record the subform jumps to has a PK that is equal to the PK of the entry in the audit log.

> **Example 2**: Bob is added to the database. We go to the subform for Bob and add his credentials. This insert command fires the trigger, and the audit table is updated with three new lines, one for each field filled in the insert. In the audit table, there is a PK called "ID", and the last entry has ID 379. The credential subform then "jumps" to the credential record where the PK of the credential record is 379.

So basically Access is refreshing the subform to a location based on an ID generated for a table that has nothing to do with the actual table that subform is based on.

Any ideas on how to curb or fix this behaviour? There's no point to any of this if the user has to refresh the forms every time they add a new person. It should also be noted that this is only on new. Editing/updating existing records? No problem. These also fire the same triggers and make audit log entries all the same. It's just on insert/new.

Comment: Do you have rights on the SQL Server? Try disabling the trigger(s) and see if the behavior is still there. (Good forensics so far BTW!) (What version of Access?)

Comment: I've struggled with this one for quite a while too. As far as I know, adjusting the trigger as described in the duplicate is the only solution

Comment: Thank you @Rikalous. 

I have dbcreator rights on this particular server, and have logged into SSMS to disable the triggers. I can confirm that if the triggers are disabled, the behaviour ceases, but the trigger has to removed completely (example, setting trigger to only fire on update and delete instead of just insert maintains behaviour. Just flat out disabling it is fine. Not sure why.) 

Versions: Access: 2016. SQL Server: 2016 SP2.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Perfect, thank you. Your search-fu is better than mine. Let me attempt this and get back to you.

This gives me an alternative idea, too. The trigger can be changed, but alternatively, since the audit table is written to a lot but very rarely actually queried, it might make more sense to make it a heap and forgo the identity usage altogether. 

I will play around.

Comment: As you can see, I'm the author of that question, Gord Thompson's search fu is what saved me ;) I personally have a dislike for heaps, but am 99.9% sure that will work

Comment: A quick test of both solutions worked, both the heap test example and the modification as linked. 

You're a life-saver. If this went on any longer, I'd be bald from pulling my hair out. 

Much obliged. I'm new to SO so I'm not sure how to give rep for a comment answer but I'll mark this fixed.